# Docker doesn't download recommended packages

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using docker for a Python application.

```
FROM python:3.5-slim
WORKDIR /abc
ADD . /abc
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
        gcc \
        python3-dev \
        musl-dev \ 
    && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt &&\
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&\
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove gcc
```

So whenever I am running the `docker build` command it first runs the `apt-get update` command there.

With update command, it's also downloading many recommended packages and taking long build time.

How can I stop Ubuntu from installing recommended packages and build docker faster?

Note: In the Dockerfile, `apt-get --no-install-recommends update` is not working; it's still downloading packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-get update` should not install anything. The only thing `apt-get update` should do is update the local description of what packages are available. That does not download those packages though -- it just downloads the updated descriptions. That can take a while.

`apt-get install` will of course install packages. In order to install those packages, it needs to download them. Using `--no-install-recommends` tells `apt-get` to not install "recommended packages". For example, if you install `vim`, there are many plugins that are also recommended and provided as separate packages. With that switch, those vim plugins will not be installed. Of course, installing the packages you selected can also take a while.

What you're doing, using `&& \` is to put all of that into a *single* docker command. So every time you *rebuild* your image, you will have to do that *every time* because the list of packages changes *every day*, sometimes even multiple times per day.

Try moving `pip install -r requirements.txt` to its own `RUN` command after you've run `apt-get` stuff. If that then does what you want, then I suggest reading and learning more about how Docker works under the hood. In particular, it's important to understand how each single command adds a new layer and how any dynamic information in a single layer can cause long build times because the layer will frequently change with large amounts of changes.

Additionally, you might want to move `ADD . /abc` to after the `RUN` commands. Any changes you've made to the files being added (source code, I assume) will invalidate the layer which represents the `apt-get` command that has been executed. Since it's been invalidated, it will need to be rebuilt. If you're actively working on and developing those projects, that can easily cause `apt-get` to be executed *every time* you build your image.

There are plenty of resources you can search for which discuss how to optimize your time when using Docker. I won't recommend any *specific* one and will leave it to you for learning.

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer it's really helpful and i am constantly working on improving the docker file for the project. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: But since i am using python:3.5-slim i have to run each any every time `apt-get update` is there any option this command taking more time?

Comment: I get the impression that English isn't your native language. It's difficult for me to understand what you're saying. Have you tried moving your `ADD` statement so that it is after your `RUN` statement?

Comment: You care right i can do that moving the `ADD` statement but this is only half docker file. I am also running node with python so multi-stage docker images is there.

Comment: Take the concept that I've shown to you. Generalize it to other commands. That should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot working on it to improve the docker file.